# Send Server Sent DOM event to specific IP with PHP

Tags: php, server-sent-events

I have a PHP cron job that checks for new emails once every minute. I can fetch the IP addresses for every account from my database via the authentication log no problem. What I'm *not* sure about is how to send the Server Sent DOM event to specific IP addresses.

The basic...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$message = 'Example Message.';
?>
```

This is *NOT* something that can be initiated from the client at all since it is a *cron job*. It is perfectly okay if one/any/all account holders don't have a browser open and ready to accept the notification, they are aware of that requirement.

This question is explicitly how to send a signal from the server to the client and *has nothing to do with the client* other then sending a signal to their IP address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have to use `fsockopen()`...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/event-stream');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
$ip = '127.0.0.1';
$message = 'Example Message.';
$result1 = fsockopen($ip,80,200,$message,30);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initiate any communication from a web server to a client. The client must first send a request in response to which your server may send the required information.